# std::map find fails when key is pointer

Tags: c++11, stdmap

I am unable to get the std::map find to locate the correct row in the std::map.  The key is a class pointer and I have created a struct (tdEcApplDataMapEq) to compare the class's binary arrays for a match.'

The problem is it doesn't work.  I call FoEcApplData::operator== when the find starts.  It says the first entry does not a match and then the find returns out pointing to the first item on the std::map list.  There is no attempt by find to search the other map entries.  Also the one match test failed (false), so why is find saying its a match?

This probably has something to do with the std::map declaration.  std::map says the third argument is for std::less, but I am doing a == vs. <.
If I change it to do < the same this happens.  It enters FoEcApplData::operator< which return a true on the first check and find search stops with the search pointing to the 1st entry in the list.

How do I get find() to use the custom struct for the search?

My example adds 10 rows to FdTEcApplDataMap.  It copies the CDH_DISABLE_XACT182 class into hold for the search later.  I then do the find() test using hold as the search key.

```
Inside entry1
Inside entry2
Inside entry3<== this is the one I am searching for
Inside entry4
Inside entry5
Inside entry6
Inside entry7
Inside entry8
Inside entry9
Inside entry10
Inside entry1
```

This is the find:

```
    auto hazard = ExcludedCmdDict.find(&hold);
    if(hazard != ExcludedCmdDict.end())
    {
std::cout << "found it " << hazard->second << std::endl;
    }
```

This is the compare function being used:

```
bool FoEcApplData::operator==( const FoEcApplData& FoEcApplDataObject) const {

    if(myNumOfBytes <= FoEcApplDataObject.NumOfBytes()) 
    { 
        const EcTOctet* temp; 
        temp = FoEcApplDataObject.Data() ; 

        for(EcTInt i = 0; i < myNumOfBytes ; i++)
        { 
            if(myData[i] != temp[i])
            { 
                return false ; 
            } 
        } 
        return true;
    } 
    else        // myNumOfBytes > FoEcApplDataObject.NumOfBytes()
    {
        const EcTOctet* temp; 
        temp = FoEcApplDataObject.Data() ; 

        for(EcTInt i = 0; i < FoEcApplDataObject.NumOfBytes(); i++)
        {
            if(myData[i] != temp[i])
            { 
                return false ; 
            } 
        } 
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is the declaration for the std::map.

```
/*
Custom less for find on the FdTEcApplDataMap.
Needed since we are using pointers.

Returns - true - match, false - no match

node  - pointer to the item you are looking for
node2 - pointer to an item on the list
*/

struct tdEcApplDataMapEq {
    bool operator()(FoEcApplData *const& node, FoEcApplData *const& node2) const
    {
        return *node == *node2;
    }
};
typedef std::map< FoEcApplData *, std::string, tdEcApplDataMapEq> FdTEcApplDataMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::map` expects the compare function to work like [`std::less`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less). You need to use something along the lines of:

```
struct tdEcApplDataMapEq {
    bool operator()(FoEcApplData *const& node, FoEcApplData *const& node2) const
    {
        return (*node < *node2); // Implement operator<() function for FoEcApplData 
    }
};
```

While at it, change the name of the `struct` to reflect the fact that it is trying to compute "less than".

```
struct tdEcApplDataMapLess {
    bool operator()(FoEcApplData *const& node, FoEcApplData *const& node2) const
    {
        return (*node < *node2); // Implement operator<() function for FoEcApplData 
    }
};
```

Comment: As I stated in the post, I tried the less "return (*node < *node2);" first and it didn't work because the "bool FoEcApplData::operator<( const FoEcApplData& FoEcApplDataObject) const {" is coded to test the length of the array vs. whats in it.  This is old code that I am modifying to use standard containers so I didn't want to change it fearing it will change the behavior of the code.  I will have to check and see if the < is being used in the code.  But I might have to manually loop the map and test each key for a match as a workaround.

Comment: @user3416126, a bug in the implementation of `FoEcApplData::operator<()` would be an obvious problem. It's hard for me to suggest anything useful to address that since I don't that what that type represents.